# How to get maximum value in an ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, compare

I want to know how to compare the all array list element in the array list? Eg I want to compare element which is the largest number. Like comparing 1st element and 2nd element, 2nd element compares to the 3rd element. How to do it?

```
List <Product> productList= new ArrayList<>();
```

Can anyone give some example on how to compare with this variable?

```
productList.get(i).getPrice()
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: do you need to *Sort* the list?

Comment: dont need, I want to get the largest number in the arraylist

Comment: yeah, sort your array and get first or last element

Comment: then check every value using `for` loop, and store the largest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want max value then use this:

```
public int getMax(ArrayList list){
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i) > max){
            max = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

and more good way is comparator:

```
public class compareProduct implements Comparator<Product> {
    public int compare(Product a, Product b) {
        if (a.getPrice() > b.getPrice())
            return -1; // highest value first
        if (a.getPrice() == b.getPrice())
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and then just do this:

`Product p = Collections.max(products, new compareProduct());`

Comment: Shortest version `Integer.compare(a.getPrice(), b.getPrice())`

Answer (score 0):

Compare some thing like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {

  for (int j = i+1; j < productList.size(); j++) {

    // compare productList.get(i)  and productList.get(j)

  }
}
```

Comment: why to use inner loop? You can compare `productList.get(i)` and `max`